# PHP: Каков оптимальный способ записать xml в документ Microsoft Word (без библиотеки)?

Tags: php, xml, ms-word, xmlparser, запись

Уважаемые эксперты!

Получаю парсером XML выдачи Yandex (см. картинку), хочу на его основе заполнять отчет в Word (ссылка, дата, заголовок и т.д.). Как это сделать? В интернете предлагают библиотеку PHPWORD, COM-соединение, xml расширения самого Word..

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А какой способ самый оптимальный и простой? Мой код написан на PHP, парсинг осуществляется библиотекой PHP Query. Попробовал заполнить документ так:

```
echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($value);
    var_dump($result);
    echo '</pre>';
       $fp = fopen("xml.docx", "a+");
     fwrite($fp, $result);
       fclose($fp);
```

что-то при этом записывается, но это что-то Word не хочет открывать... Пишет: к сожалению не удается открыть файл xml.docx из-за проблем с его содержимым". Подскажите, пожалуйста, по какому пути лучше пойти в решении проблемы?

Comment: можно просто html код написать и дать ему расширение .doc. Word откроет без проблем. Вид будет web документ

Comment: А как это сделать? Или как способ называется, чтобы узнать больше о таком способе?

Comment: не знаю, как называется.

Comment: вот тут наверняка что-нить есть https://yandex.ru/search/?text=php%20html%20to%20word&lr=219&clid=2270455&win=280

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!